# Updated default close reason is not being displayed

Tags: support

The default "close reason" was edited to
"This question's **quality does not meet the standards** within the scope defined in the [help]. Please read around the [help] and feel free to edit and reopen when it is improved."

However, we are not seeing it as an option for closing questions.

How can we see it and start using it?